# Is there a way for checking the count of users who used Google login using the client-id provided by Google

Tags: authentication, google-account, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I have an app that uses Google login as one of the modes for login/signup the users in the app. Unfortunately, I missed saving the user-id received after logging-in using Google, and therefore, I can't seem to find the users who have used Google for creating the account on my app.

Is there a way I can track the count of the users who has used the Google login using the [client-id](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) Google provides while integrating the Google login button?